# node trying to remove JOI module getting error warning?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, package.json, joi

I am trying to remove Joi moule from node (because im not using it in app) and as its giving me this error:

```
/home/ubuntu/socialtrendsApp/app/SocialTrends/node_modules/joi/lib/index.js:48
    root.any = function (...args) {
                         ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/socialtrendsApp/app/SocialTrends/index.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
```

I typed: `npm uninstall joi --save -g` which is giving me the following warning: `npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.5/lib/node_modules: "joi"`

Need to get rid of this error or remove this modile. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this module globally installed with the same node.js version?

Comment: fixed, it was local removed -g

Comment: I hope the comment helped :)